# How to find the big O notation of $\log^b x$

Tags: asymptotics

How would you determine big O notation for $\log^b x$? I don't think you can simply say $O(\log^b x)$, can you?

If you can, then here is a better question: $x^3 + \log^b x$. How would you know if it's $O(x^3)$ or something else depending on the $b$ value?

Comment: It's certainly in $O(2^n)$. [What is your real question?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use) Also, [my answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/16818/98) to your other question should solve your problem here, too. See [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth) for the general desecription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would you determine big o notation for this? I don't think you can simply do O(log(x)^b) can you?

$\mathcal O\left(\log^b x\right)$ or $\mathcal O\left(\left(\log x\right)^b\right)$ is correct.

> x^3 + log(x)^b

Assuming $b$ is a constant. You always take the fastest growing term in a polynomial. $T(x)=\mathcal O\left(\log^b x\right)$ is called *polylogarithmic time*. In this case, $\mathcal O\left(x^3\right)$ grows faster than $\mathcal O\left(\log^b x\right)$.

You can see a list of different complexities (sorted from lowest to highest) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities).

Comment: What's $T(x)$? Who said anything about time? It's best to avoid introducing extraneous details and say that a function is *polylogarithmic* if it is a polynomial in $\log x$ (i.e., has the form $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\log^i x$).

Comment: @DavidRicherby feel free to edit.

Answer (score 2):

To answer any question about $O(-)$ notation, you need to check the definition, which is that, for functions $f$ and $g$, $f=O(g)$ if, and only if, there are constants $x_0$ and $k$ such that $|f(x)|\leq k|g(x)|$ for all $x\geq x_0$.

$O(-)$ is often treated as some fixed hierarchy of functions, "logarithms are $O$(polynomials), polynomials are $O$(exponentials)" and so on, leading students to believe that you can only write $O(g)$ for some very special or very nice functions $g$. This is quite simply not true: the definition allows you to write $O(g)$ for any function of one variable that you want to. For constant $b$, you can write $O(\log^b x)$. Heck, you can write $O\big(\sin\,(\cos\tfrac{1}{x^2})+3\big)$, if you want to, though you probably never will want that.

Answer (score 0):

A good "rule of thumb" to use with asymptotic notation is:
$O(n^n) > O(k^n) > O(n^k \log^l n) > O(n^k) > O(log^k n) > O(1)$

So if you have $n^3 + log^b n$, the $n^3$ term will dominate, giving you $O(n^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in O(f(n)) notation, we well try to find a *simple* function f, and we will try to find one that isn't growing much faster than the left hand side. (So we wouldn't say that n + 3 = O(n^2) usually even though it is completely true). We would probably write that (2 + sin (n^2)) n = O (n), because it's true, it's a simple function, and it is quite close - the left side is *not* little-O(n); it's always between n and 3n.

And it's relatively easy to show that x^3 is NOT O (log^b n) for any b.

In your case, O (log^b n) is perfectly fine. There's nothing that is both simpler and close to log^b n.